# ModelFactory não está gerando dados do $faker para algumas tabelas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estou usando o `ModelFactory` padrão do Laravel 5 já há algum tempo, e estava indo tudo ok, mas de uns dias pra cá parou de gerar dados da biblioteca `faker` para algumas tabelas, apesar de continuar normalmente para outras.

Quando rodo `php artisan db:seed -vvv` com as definições abaixo, a tabela `client` é preenchida corretamente, com todos os valores, e a tabela `email` acaba com 100 linhas de valores default ou vazios.

Alguma ideia de por onde começar a debugar isso?

database/factory/ModelFactory.php (default)

```
$factory->define(App\Client::class, function ($faker) {
    $origins = DB::table('origin')->lists('id');
    $methods = DB::table('entry_method')->lists('id');
    $image = str_replace('public', '', $faker->image('public/img', '100', '100', 'cats'));
    return [
        'name' => $faker->firstName,
        'middlename' => $faker->lastName,
        'lastname' => $faker->lastName,
        'birthday' => $faker->date(),
        'type' => $faker->randomElement(array('nao-associado','patrimonial','cooperador','coletivo','entidade','emerito','individual')),
        'associate_code' => $faker->randomNumber(),
        'identification' => str_random(20),
        'identification_type' => $faker->randomElement(array('rg','cpf','cnh','passaporte','social-security','outro')),
        'language' => $faker->randomElement(array('pt','en')),
        'foreigner' => $faker->boolean(),
        'image' => $image,
        'vip' => $faker->numberBetween(0,1),
        'id_origin' => $faker->randomElement($origins),
        'id_entry_method' => $faker->randomElement($methods),
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\Email::class, function ($faker) {
    $clients = DB::table('client')->lists('id');
    return [
        'email' => $faker->companyEmail,
        'type' => $faker->randomElement(array('pessoal','comercial')),
        'id_client' => $faker->randomElement($clients),
    ];
});
```

database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Connection;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');

        factory('App\Client', 100)->create();
        factory('App\Email', 100)->create();
        // create
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');

        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

app/Email.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Email extends Model
{
    public $domains;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'email';
    protected $fillable = ['email', 'type', 'mailchimp_id', 'id_client'];

}
```

EDIT: migrations

```
    Schema::create('client', function(Blueprint $table) 
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 50);
        $table->string('middlename', 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('lastname', 50);
        $table->date('birthday')->nullable();
        $table->enum('type', ['nao-associado','patrimonial',
                              'cooperador','coletivo',
                              'entidade','emerito',
                              'individual'])->default('nao-associado');
        $table->string('associate_code', 45)->nullable(); // codigo_socio
        $table->string('identification'); // documento identidade
        $table->enum('identification_type', ['rg','cpf','cnh','passaporte','social-security','outro']); // codigo_socio
        $table->enum('language', ['pt','en'])->default('pt'); 
        $table->boolean('foreigner')->default(false);
        $table->string('password', 255)->nullable(); // documento identidade
        $table->string('image', 255); // foto
        $table->boolean('vip')->default(false);

        // Foreign keys
        $table->integer('id_entry_method')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('id_origin')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('id_client')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('id_entry_method')->references('id')->on('entry_method');
        $table->foreign('id_origin')->references('id')->on('origin');
        $table->foreign('id_client')->references('id')->on('client');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });

    Schema::create('email', function(Blueprint $table) 
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email', 50);
        $table->enum('type', ['pessoal','comercial']);
        $table->string('mailchimp_id', 100);
        $table->integer('id_client')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('id_client')->references('id')->on('client');
    });
```

Comment: Poderia postar a migration dessas duas tabelas? Gostaria de reproduzir aqui. Talvez você precise adicionar uma contra barra antes de executar dos lists: `\DB::`

Comment: @gmsantos adicionei as migrations. não testei ainda com `\DB::` mas acho pouco provável que seja isso porque as chamadas pra DB funcionam em `client`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em sua tabela `email` existe o campo `mailchimp_id` que não foi definido no seu *Model Factory* e também não tem um valor *default* na *migration*.

Modifiquei sua *Factory* aqui e deu certo:

```
$factory->define(App\Email::class, function ($faker) {
    $clients = DB::table('client')->lists('id');
    return [
        'email' => $faker->companyEmail,
        'type' => $faker->randomElement(array('pessoal','comercial')),
        'mailchimp_id' => str_random(25),  
        'id_client' => $faker->randomElement($clients),
    ];
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: bizarro, fiz o mesmo aqui e o erro persiste, inclusive coloquei o campo como nullable() na migration. O que me espanta é o `db:seed` não gerar nenhum erro mesmo com `-vvv`. To começando a desconfiar de timeout ou algo assim.

Comment: @moraleida está usando qual DB? Aqui rodei com o MySQL e só de rodar `db:seed` sem verbose ele começou a gritar erro de PDO.

Comment: MySQL aqui, rodando normal pras outras tabelas. muito esquisito. tem jeito de rodar  só um seed especifico?

Comment: Pode rodar um único arquivo de seed `php artisan db:seed --class=UserTableSeeder`

Comment: @moraleida o que acontece se você tirar a FK da migration email?

Comment: nada. rodei `composer update` por via das duvidas, migrei o email seeder pra uma classe própria pra rodar sozinho, tirei as FKs, continua tudo igual, email em branco e defaults. 

`+-----+-------+---------+--------------+
| id  | email | type    | mailchimp_id |
+-----+-------+---------+--------------+
|   1 |       | pessoal | NULL         |`

Comment: Tente limpar a tabela email antes de executar a seed com `DB::table('email')->truncate()`